# Simplecart makes IE11 crash on win8

Tags: wordpress, windows-8, internet-explorer-11, simplecart

I've installed simplecart on a wordpress site 
http://www.pixelligentdev.com/products/
It works fine on firefox - chrome - but not in IE11 on win8 / win10 and I can't find the issue because with debugger tool open it doesn't crash !

If you try to buy a product clicking on "order" button you'll see

[image]

Comment: capture a crash dump with **procdump -ma -i C:\dumps**, open the dmp with Windbg, fix symbols (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us), run **!analyze -v** and look if you see anything useful.

Comment: have you tried to debug it?

Comment: thanks @magicandre1981 It was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed!
To track it back to source I’ve run IE with VS (Visual Studio) attached + public symbols.

The issue is a IE11 bug related to the storage events and localstorage usage. The bug was not happening when DEV tools  was enabled because opening the console will set the mode to “Edge”.

Unfortunately the Microsoft’s reply is:
“This issue appears to have been fixed in Microsoft Edge. We're not presently working on feature bugs in Internet Explorer outside of security-related issues.”

The workaround is simple.
You can force IE11 to load the backwards compatibility mode to IE10.

The MS new browser (Edge) is not following that directive and IE <=10 are   also ignoring it.

This can be done by adding a X-UA-Compatible meta,but this approach is not 
recommended.

Instead I’ve pushed it via the header (.htaccess) to avoid  page validation errors.

Changes in .htaccess

• I’ve Added to header “X-UA-Compatible” mode that will force IE11 to render as IE10.( backwards    compatibility)

**Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE10"**